# Sqlalchemy save to memory

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My app needs to save changes whilst offline and upload them when it reconnects.

I know I could use SQLite, json, ect to save them too but would really like it if I could get sqlalchemy to commit to memory instead to cut down the code. I am not concerned about powerloss or program crashes atm.

I assumed using sessions.add() would do this and that when it reconnected sessions.commit() would commit all changes, but it seems to get overwritten when I add another.

Is this possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLite to do an [in-memory database](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlite):

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
```

Take a look at your [`autoflush`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=add#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.params.autoflush) setting:

> When True, all query operations will issue a flush() call to this Session before proceeding. This is a convenience feature so that flush() need not be called repeatedly in order for database queries to retrieve results. It’s typical that autoflush is used in conjunction with autocommit=False. In this scenario, explicit calls to flush() are rarely needed; you usually only need to call commit() (which flushes) to finalize changes.

It may be working against you, as [`add`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=add#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add) states that:

> Place an object in the Session.
>   Its state will be persisted to the database on the next flush operation.
>   Repeated calls to add() will be ignored. The opposite of add() is expunge().

Other popular options for short-term data storage include [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: Thanks. I went with Redis in the end. Works out pretty well